# Xcode error when building Vapor 3 framework

Tags: swift, vapor

I had this error when trying to build from XCode , albeit it builds from terminal

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/++/Desktop/vapor/til/.build/checkouts/sqlite.git--8232814251736334455/Sources/CSQLite/sqlite3.c'
>   clang: error: no input files

I'm using pgsql and this is my configure.swift

```
// 1
import FluentPostgreSQL
import Vapor

public func configure(
    _ config: inout Config,
    _ env: inout Environment,
    _ services: inout Services
) throws {
    // 2
    try services.register(FluentPostgreSQLProvider())

    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig()
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self)
    services.register(middlewares)

    // 1
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    // 2
    let hostname = Environment.get("DATABASE_HOSTNAME")
        ?? "localhost"
    let username = Environment.get("DATABASE_USER") ?? "vapor"
    let databaseName = Environment.get("DATABASE_DB") ?? "vapor"
    let password = Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
        ?? "password"
    // 3
    let databaseConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(
        hostname: hname,
        username: username,
        database: databasesName,
        password: password)
    // 4
    let database = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: databaseConfig)
    // 5
    databases.add(database: database, as: .psql)
    // 6
    services.register(databases)

    var migrations = MigrationConfig()
    // 4
    migrations.add(model: Acronym.self, database: .psql)
    services.register(migrations)
}
```

I removed XCode and reinstalled it but no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making sure that you removed any traces of the `fluent-sqlite` package from your `Package.swift` file (since your code suggests using PostgreSQL now), please try deleting your `.build` folder, along with a few regeneratable items with the following commands:

```
rm -rf .build
rm -rf til.xcodeproj # or however is your Xcode project file called
rm Package.resolved
```

Then you can re-generate your Xcode project with `vapor xcode` and/or you can try building from command line again.